# Is there a PDOStatement "executed" flag?

Tags: php, pdo

Is there such a thing like an "executed" flag for `PDOStatement` ([PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)) to see if the statement has been executed (by calling `PDOStatement::execute()`)? Or am I forced to just set my own flag?

Judging by the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a flag (the only documented property is `$queryString`) - but I thought I'ld still ask before doing it manually. Mainly to distinguish prepared from already executed statements.

Comment: An interesting question. Looks like there is none. Though you're seems the only person that needs such a flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a statement is prepared, you can execute it multiple times, so maybe the builders didn't think a flag like that would be useful, and personally I'm a bit curious about your use case too.

But it is possible: Using [PDOStatement::errorCode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php), you can get the error code of the last statement. This function will return an exmpty string when the statement is not executed yet, and will be filled with an error code, (or `00000` for no error), after the statement is executed.

Comment: I guess that's the only way to tell then! I knew that it can be reused/executed multiple times, but I wanted to avoid re-executing a prepared statement that is being passed around / not executed right away.

Comment: @Katai why would you want to pass around a prepared statement instead of passing around its result? Relying on the undocumented tricks is a slippery matter you know.

Comment: @YourCommonSense To allow late binding of parameters before execution (like setting limit / offset when paging is present).

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. You can reuse a PDOStatement, which is the use case supported with [PDO:prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).